# Drop Down with sqlite - Flutter

Tags: list, sqlite, dart, flutter, dropdown

I have database sqlite data and i want to show my data in drop down with changed id of my rows in table because in future i want to create another drop down to change to value of first drop down anyone can help ?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843146/flutter-sqflite-populate-a-dropdown-list-from-the-database)

Answer (score 2):

### Working with SQLite on flutter

To gather the data from a SQLite database you could use the [sqflite plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) (independently if is an iOS or Android device).  You have to add the dependency to your `pubspec.yaml`.

```
dependencies:
  ...
  sqflite: any
```

When you want to use sqflite you have to import the library.

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
```

Next, you have to open a connection to SQLite, here we create a table in case you didn't have one

```
Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE Test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER, num REAL)');
});
```

You can insert or retrieve data using `database.rawQuery`.

Insert:

```
int primaryKeyInsertedRow = await database.rawQuery('INSERT INTO Test(name, value, num) VALUES("some name", 1234, 456.789)');
```

Select:

```
List<Map> list = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Test');
```

Remember to close the database when you are done with it.

```
await database.close();
```

### Displaying a drop down menu list

For displaying the data you retrieve first you have to create a class that extends `StatefulWidget`, override the `createState()` method, and set your own state (in this example, `SettingWidgetState`)

```
@override
_SettingsWidgetState createState() => new _SettingsWidgetState();
```

Second you should define a state for it, defining a class that extends `State<NameOfYourWidget>`. In that class you should have a list of `DropdownMenuItem<String>` and a string member of the current selected element.

For the sake of convenience, in this example we are going to use a static list of cities:

```
List _cities = [
  "Cluj-Napoca",
  "Bucuresti",
  "Timisoara",
  "Brasov",
  "Constanta"
];
```

Next, we override `initState()` setting our list of `DropDownMenuItem` to our list and the currently selected list element. After that we should call `super.initState()`.

Also, we need to override the `build()` method. The goal is to return a `Container` that contains a `DropDownButton`, and that `DropDownButton` has assigned the list of items (defined in the class), the selected element (also defined in the class) and a event handler for the `onChanged:` property (here also are inserted additional widgets with the purpose of making it look nice)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: new Center(
        child: new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text("Please choose your city: "),
        new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        ),
        new DropdownButton(
          value: _currentCity,
          items: _dropDownMenuItems,
          onChanged: changedDropDownItem,
        )
      ],
    )),
  );
}
```

Lastly we define the method that is going to be called when a new item is selected from the list (`changeDropDownItem(string selectedCity)` in our example).

```
  void changedDropDownItem(String selectedCity) {
    setState(() {
      _currentCity = selectedCity;
    });
  }
}
```

[Link](https://medium.com/@boldijar.paul/comboboxes-in-flutter-cabc9178cc95) where I based my answer for drop down list.  You can check out too [getting started with sqflite plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite)

Comment: Links in answers should be used as supplementary resources or citations. Please do not rely on them for the bulk of your answer. Links can go dead, or the information on the other end can be changed to no longer answer the question. Please edit your answer to include the information you have linked to.

Comment: I modified the post to actually answer the question, sorry for only provide links

Comment: I think i will thank you for your answer but i know how to implement database my problem was to show from it in drop down but it now solved