# Flutter SQFlite populate a dropdown list from the database

Tags: flutter

I am trying to read the list part of a dropdown list from my SQFlite database, and can't work out how.

Query from database_helper

```
Future<List<Map>> getFieldData(String animal, String fieldName)
 var dbClient = await db;

return await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT lbOption FROM jkAssessData Where lbAnimal = \'${animal}\' AND lbField = \'${fieldName}\'');
```

}

I can get it to work with a static list of values

```
  final List<String> _animals = <String>['CATTLE', 'SHEEP', 'GOAT'];
```

to populate this dropdown list

```
      FormField<String>(
        builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
          return InputDecorator(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Animal Type',
              errorText: state.hasError ? state.errorText : null,
            ),
            isEmpty: _animal == '',
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: _animal,
                isDense: true,
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    assessHed.asAnimal = newValue;
                    _animal = newValue;
                    state.didChange(newValue);
                  });
                },
                items: _animals.map((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        validator: (val) {
          //return val != 'SUMMARY' ? 'DETAIL' : 'Please select Type';
          return null;
        },
      ),
```

It's part of several fields on a Form

Comment: looks like you forgot to put the call to `getFieldData`, did you try something as `initState() { getFieldData().then(() { setState(() => _animals = ..yourStuff..); }); }` ?

Comment: did you also notice you're returning a `List<Map>` and you're doing `_animals.map((String) ...)`?

Comment: I didn't include the call to the function. The dropdown using _animals.map() is just a static one with those 3 known values, I need to be able to populate other from the database.

Comment: I'm not sure where to call something like List<Map> _breeds = await db.getFieldData('CATTLE','Breed1') it mentions can't assign Future<List<Map>> to type List<Map> Do I need to use a FutureBuilder ? I am new to flutter. I thought I could just return a List of type String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by using the call in the `initState` or in a `onPressed` of a `RaisedButton`.

Place this `initState` and `_loadAnimals` method in your `State` Widget.

```
  List<String> _animals = <String>[];

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    // when loading your widget for the first time, loads animals from sqflite
    _loadAnimals();
  }

  _loadAnimals() async {
    // gets data from sqflite
    final loadedAnimals = await getFieldData('CATTLE','Breed1');
    setState(() {
      // converts sqflite row data to List<String>, updating state
      _animals = loadedAnimals.map((Map<dynamic, dynamic> row) => row["lbOption"] as String).toList();
    });
  }
```

Or you could change the `getFieldData` to return a `List<String>` instead of a `List<Map>`:

```
  Future<List<String>> getFieldDataAsString(String animal, String fieldName) async {
    var dbClient = await db;

    var results = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT lbOption FROM jkAssessData Where lbAnimal = \'$animal\' AND lbField = \'$fieldName\'');

    return results.map((Map<String, dynamic> row) {
      return row["lbOption"] as String;
    }).toList();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, that cleared things up for me. I was following an sqflite example that used Future<List<Map>> and it is much simpler to return a List of Strings for the dropdown list values.

Comment: You're welcome, if you think it helped, don't forget to accept as an answer. Cheers

Comment: i get method .map() not defined for the type future. when trying to put .map() on my data